# Read UTF-8 in Java from Excel txt export

Tags: java, excel, encoding, utf-8

I'm having some problems with something simple and it's doing my head in. I have some entries in an Excel spreadsheet that contains various Asian characters etc. When exported as "Unicode text (*.txt)" with UTF-8 selected as encoding I can view it correctly in Notepad, but when I try to print it in the Eclipse console I get gibberish. I've tried variations as to how to read as UTF-8 and I know the console can display it:

```
    try {
        //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testtest.txt"));
        File fileDir = new File("testestet.txt");
        //PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8"); // tried this just in case
        System.out.println("사과"); // this prints just fine
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String line;
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Any ideas? Whatever I solution I've found here has not worked. I'm wondering if excel is just borked...

Comment: The [tag:eclipse] tag might be relevant here, given that you're outputting to the Eclipse problem. You might also want to check their bug database to see if there are any known issues regarding Unicode support in the console.

Comment: It could be that the `Terminal Console Font` selected in eclipse does not support the characters you try to display. You could try and select a different font in eclipse under Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> Terminal Console Font.

Comment: I added the part about the console so it wouldn't be suggested as a fix ;) Like I mentioned, the console can display the characters (the example in the code, "System.out.println("사과");", prints correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Should you try this instead?

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: Ah, my bad. I had UTF_8 but wrote ISO for whatever reason. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Heh, I found the problem while testing all StandardCharsets. UTF-16 works! I guess some of the characters I had in my Excel spreadsheet weren't supported by UTF-8 and Excel solved the problem without telling me...